# Problem accessing values from YAML file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am building a hangman game and am trying to add save game and load game functionality. I have saved a game using the following method inside my Hangman class.

```
def save_game
    File.open('saved_game.yml', 'w') { |f| YAML.dump([] << self, f) }
    puts 'Game Saved!'
end
```

When I used this method mid-game I ended up with the following YAML file containing the instance variables at that point in the game:

```
---
- !ruby/object:Hangman
  secret_word: sc---nshots
  secret_word_immutable: screenshots
  secret_word_display:
  - _
  - _
  - r
  - e
  - e
  - _
  - _
  - _
  - _
  - _
  - _
  guesses: 4
  end_game: 0
  wrong_letters_guessed: []
  right_letters_guessed:
  - e
  - r
```

The problem occurs when I try to access the values of the saved instance variables (secret_word, secret_word_immutable, etc...) from the YAML file, and use them to update the initialized values of the variables in a new game.

My load_game method looks like this:

```
  def load_game
    yaml = YAML.load_file('saved_game.yml')
    @secret_word = yaml.dig('secret_word')
    @secret_word_immutable = yaml.dig('secret_word_immutable')
    @secret_word_display = yaml.dig('secret_word_display')
    @guesses = yaml.dig('guesses')
    @end_game = yaml.dig('end_game')
    @wrong_letters_guessed = yaml.dig('wrong_letters_guessed')
    @right_letters_guessed = yaml.dig('right_letters_guessed')
    puts "Saved game loaded!"
  end
```

I have tried different methods of accessing the YAML values, including using bracket notation instead of #dig and using #fetch. I have also tried chaining these methods together and passing the instance variable in as a symbol or string. All methods produce type errors.

I think the problem might have something to do with the fact that the YAML file begins with:

```
- !ruby/object:Hangman
```

because while using 'p' to try to figure out what is going on I access the length, class, and value of 'yaml' and yaml[0] I get:

```
p yaml.length     #=> 1
p yaml.class      #=> Array
p yaml            #=> #<Hangman:0x00007fa771234090>
p yaml[0]         #=> #<Hangman:0x00007fa771234090 @secret_word="sc---nshots", @secret_word_immutable="screenshots", @secret_word_display=["_", "_", "r", "e", "e", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"], @guesses=4, @end_game=0, @wrong_letters_guessed=[], @right_letters_guessed=["e", "r"]>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: `YAML.dump([] << self, f` is adding your object to an empty array. Do you need to save the data in an array?

Answer (score 0):

`YAML.dump([] << self, f)` is pushing your object onto an empty array. It's an obfuscated way of writing `YAML.dump([self], f)`.

Your object is the first element in that array. You'd access the first object.

```
@secret_word = yaml[0].dig('secret_word')
```

---

There doesn't seem to be a purpose to dumping a single element array here, dump just `self`: `YAML.dump(self, f)`

Then you can use it directly.

```
@secret_word = yaml.dig('secret_word')
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my save_game method to use: YAML.dump(self, f)
When I try using it directly with #dig as you suggest I get:  undefined method `dig'
why does it not recognize this method?

Comment: when I check : ```yaml.class```
 I get : Hangman
It seems like dig needs to be used with a Hash so this might be why I am getting a NoMethodError ?

Comment: @mikerachman1 `!ruby/object:Hangman` says "this is a Ruby Hangman object" so YAML loads it as a Hangman object, not as a Hash. Write a Hangman class method which loads and returns the Hangman object directly from load_file. `def self.load_game YAML.load_file('saved_game.yml') end`